# What are guidelines for SmartPLS boostrapping case size?

Tags: bootstrap, partial-least-squares

In SmartPLS, bootstrapping is used to generate the t statistic from which statistical significance can be judged. The two main bootstrapping parameters are case and sample size. Increasing the sample only seems to ensure that the t statistic is stable. Increasing the case size seems to greatly increase the t statistics. E.g. if I have 160 observations, my t statistic for one path is about 2. If I increase the case size to 2000, the t statistic is about 7. It seems almost like cheating to use a huge case number just to get statistical significance, but I'm not aware of standard practices.

What are the guidelines for bootstrapping case size?

Comment: The number of Bootstrap samples should be ***high, but must be at least equal to the number of valid observations in your dataset.*** In another words, the recommended number of bootstrap samples is **5,000.**

Comment: The question is about case size, not sample size.

Comment: If i use very small sample size like 20 for piloting the constructs, i found that i couldn't run bootstrapping..
I heard smartPLS can run smaller numbers..

Answer (score 3):

Set amount of cases equal to the number of valid observations in your dataset to get the correct t-statistics.